# Volume of system gets muted automatically

Tags: audio

My systems volume gets muted automatically when I plug in the headphones but works perfectly ok when they are unplugged. I am using elemantary OS. Please help me to sought out the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds to me like you need to check your headphone's volume settings.

- Plug in your headphones.
- Open the terminal, and run `alsamixer`. You will get something like this:

[[image]

- From here, find the option labelled "Headphones" and, if it reads "MM", press "<kbd>M</kbd>" to unmute them. You may also need to raise their volume by pressing the up arrow.

For good measure, ensure that automute is enabled as well (it most likely is, but still double check).